# String.replaceAll() is not working for some strings

Tags: java, string, str-replace

I am editing some email that got from tesseract ocr.

**Here is my code:**

```
 if (email != null) {
        email = email.replaceAll(" ", "");
        email = email.replaceAll("caneer", "career");
        email = email.replaceAll("canaer", "career");
        email = email.replaceAll("canear", "career");
        email = email.replaceAll("caraer", "career");
        email = email.replaceAll("carear", "career");
        email = email.replace("|", "l");
        email = email.replaceAll("}", "j");
        email = email.replaceAll("j3b", "job");
        email = email.replaceAll("gmaii.com", "gmail.com");
        email = email.replaceAll("hotmaii.com", "hotmail.com");
        email = email.replaceAll(".c0m", ".com");
        email = email.replaceAll(".coin", ".com");
        email = email.replaceAll("consuit", "consult");
    }
    return email;
```

But the output is not correct.

**Input :**

```
amrut=ac.hrworks@g mai|.com
```

**Output :**

```
lalcl.lhlrlwlolrlklsl@lglmlalil|l.lclolml
```

But when I assigned the result to a new String after every replacement, it works fine. Why continuous assignment in the same String is not working?

Comment: When I copy/paste that in (and fix the typo on line 5), it results in what seems to be a correct result - "amrut=ac.hrworks@gmail.com".

Comment: Consider using String.replace instead of replaceAll. It does exactly what I believe you expected replaceAll to do.

Comment: My eyes hurt from seeing code like that.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You'll note in the [Javadoc for String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String)) that the first argument is a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

A period (`.`) has a special meaning there as does a pipe (`|`) as does a curly brace (`}`). You need to escape them all, such as:

```
email = email.replaceAll("gmaii\\.com", "gmail.com");
```

Comment: Do I have to escape | and {

Comment: Yes. Hence "You need to escape them all".

Comment: I escaped | by \\| But still it is not getting replaced. Everything else works fine

Comment: You're using `String.replace()` there (I didn't even notice) which is *different*. It takes a `CharSequence` as the first argument (a `String`) and you don't escape there.

Comment: though i was aware of it, it got skipped off my head ...Thank you for saving my day

Comment: the best way to escape all that needs to be escaped is `Pattern.quote(String)`

Answer (score 14):

(Is this Java?)

Note that in Java, replaceAll accepts a regular expression and the dot matches any character. You need to escape the dot or use

```
somestring.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("gmail.com"), "replacement");
```

Also note the typo here:

```
email = emai.replaceAll("canear", "career");
```

should be

```
email = email.replaceAll("canear", "career");
```

Comment: Yes, Java. Thanks for mentioning that typo error also. I corrected

Answer (score 6):

You have to escape `.` by `\\.`like following :

```
if (email != null) {
    email = email.replaceAll(" ", "");
    email = email.replaceAll("caneer", "career");
    email = email.replaceAll("canaer", "career");
    email = email.replaceAll("canear", "career");
    email = email.replaceAll("caraer", "career");
    email = email.replaceAll("carear", "career");
    email = email.replace("|", "l");
    email = email.replaceAll("}", "j");
    email = email.replaceAll("j3b", "job");
    email = email.replaceAll("gmaii\\.com", "gmail.com");
    email = email.replaceAll("hotmaii\\.com", "hotmail.com");
    email = email.replaceAll("\\.c0m", "com");
    email = email.replaceAll("\\.coin", "com");
    email = email.replaceAll("consuit", "consult");
}
return email;
```

Answer (score 6):

By realizing that `replaceAll()` first argument is `regex` you can make your comparisons much less

For example you can check for possible misspellings of the word `career` by the following `regex`

`email = email.replaceAll("ca[n|r][e|a][e|a]r", "career"));`

Comment: Should that really be `[n|r]` and friends rather than `[nr]` & Co?

Comment: Yes you can, I thought the first one is explicit and more readable

Answer (score 5):

You are using some regex characters.

Please escape them using `\` or by using `Pattern.quote` method

Answer (score 5):

I think you are not aware that first parameter of `replaceAll` is regex.

`.` , `|`, `}` might be interpreted in a different way from your expectation.

```
.   Any character (may or may not match line terminators)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

For space you better use

```
\s  A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]
```

and escape other special characters with a leading `\\`