# String.replace() java not replacing characters matching a expression

Tags: java

I'm trying to replace few characters matching an expression in a string by name `inputPath` such that if  `inputPath` contains an expression like `"json*"` then `"json*"` has to removed from that string. I did like this:

```
String newPath = inputPath.replace("json*","");
```

When I print `newPath`, I am getting string with `"json"` being removed but `"*"` is not getting removed or replaced. But I need to get entire `"json*"` removed or replaced. I just dont understand why it's not replacing `"*"` but replacing `"json"` only.

Comment: Your code should work. Can you provide an [MCVE](/help/mcve) showing the problem?

Comment: @Tunaki Thank you solved the problem

Comment: @JavaUser Well, if it did, there's something very wrong because my comment was incorrect :D (and I have removed it).

Comment: If escaping solved the problem, as @Tunaki said, you weren't using `replace`. If you were using `replaceAll`, a trivial search of Stack Overflow would have found your solution ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826143/string-replaceall-is-not-working), for instance).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  I have solved the problem not using Tunaki's solution.I did like this to solve my problem:   String replacedPattern = input.getPattern().replace("*","")
   String replacedPath = input.getPath().replace("*","");String finalPath=replacedPath.replace(replacedPattern, "");

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The solution which you have provided in the link didn't work for me.So please remove the downvote as the solution which I have posted is not there in stackoverflow

Comment: @JavaUser: Never assume you know who voted. That said, the question as it stands right now asserts something doesn't work that **does** work and can trivially be verified to work ([example](http://ideone.com/RZOUOk)), so I'm not surprised it's been downvoted. I *am* surprised it hasn't been closed yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true and unexpected in case for replace() in String class. Probably you are using replaceAll/replaceFirst, that takes the ReGex as input. I have reproduced what you are getting.

> ```
>     String inputPath = "stackjson* overflow";
>     String newPath = inputPath.replaceAll("json*", "");
>     System.out.println(newPath);
> ```

Under that case, as * is a ReGex character so you need to escape them as using \\:

> String newPath = inputPath.replaceAll("json\\*", "");

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question that was asked. It's an answer to a different question that's already asked-and-answered (repeatedly) on the site. Comment with a link, rather than posting an answer which is (as far as we know) irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out solution for the previous problem which I have posted:
If I use :

```
String finalPath = input.getPath().replace("json*","")
           or
String finalPath = input.getPath().replace(input.getPattern(),"")
```

then I am getting output as /input/* with json removed but * not removed.Instead I did like this:

```
 String replacedPattern = input.getPattern().replace("*","");

 String replacedPath = input.getPath().replace("*","");

 String finalPath=replacedPath.replace(replacedPattern, "");
```

Now I got output as /input/ with json* removed which is expected to be.