# Why replaceAll("$","") is not working although replace("$","") works just fine?

Tags: java, string, replace, replaceall

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class GFG
{
public static void main (String[] args)
 {
       int turns;
     Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
     turns=scan.nextInt();
     while(turns-->0)
     {
       String pattern=scan.next();
       String text=scan.next();
       System.out.println(regex(pattern,text));

      }
 }//end of main method
 static int regex(String pattern,String text)
 {
     if(pattern.startsWith("^"))
       {
           if(text.startsWith(pattern.replace("^","")))
           return 1;
       }
       else if(pattern.endsWith("$"))
       {
           if(text.endsWith(pattern.replace("$","")))
           return 1;
       }
       else
       {
          if(text.contains(pattern))
          return 1; 
       }
       return 0;
 }
}
```

Input: 
2
or$
hodor
or$
arya

Output:
1
0

In this program i am scanning two parameters(String) in which first one is pattern and second one is text in which i have to find pattern. Method should return 1 if pattern matched else return 0.
While using replace it is working fine but when i replace replace() to replaceAll() it is not working properly as expected.
How can i make replaceAll() work in this program.

Comment: `replace` needs a string, `replaceAll` needs a regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826143/string-replaceall-is-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` is a scpecial character in regex (EOL). You have to escape it

```
pattern.replaceAll("\\$","")
```

Answer (score 6):

Because [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) expects a string defining a **regular expression**, and `$` means "end of line" in regular expressions. From the link:

> ```
> public String replaceAll(String regex,
>                          String replacement)
> ```
>
> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

You need to escape it with a backslash (which also has to be escaped, in the string literal):

```
if(text.endsWith(pattern.replaceAll("\\$","")))
```

For complex strings that you want to replace verbatim, [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) is useful:

```
if(text.endsWith(pattern.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("$"),"")))
```

You don't need it here because your replacement is `""`, but if your replacement may have special characters in it (like backslashes or dollar signs), use [`Matcher.quoteReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement-java.lang.String-) on the replacement string as well.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon And in replacement part [Matcher,quoteReplacement()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement-java.lang.String-) since `$` and ``\`` are also special there (`$x` to access match from group `x`, and ``\`` so we can escape `$`).

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: Ah yes, thanks, Java actually has that useful method. I keep waiting for TC-39 to add it to JavaScript. :-|

Answer (score 2):

Despite the similar name, these are two very different methods.

`replace` replaces substrings with other substrings (*).

`replaceAll` uses regular expression matching, and `$` is a special control character there (meaning "end of string/line").

You should not be using `replaceAll` here, but if you must, you have to [quote the `$`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409296/what-is-the-use-of-pattern-quote-method):

```
 pattern.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("$"),"")
```

---

(*) to make things more confusing, `replace` also replaces *all* occurances, so the only difference in the method names does not all describe the difference in function.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing another level of complexity by replacing $ by \$.

```
"$ABC$AB".replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("$"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\$"))
// Output - \\$ABC\\$AB
```

This worked for me.

For the issue reported here,

```
"$ABC$AB".replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("$"), "")
```

should work.